# Правовая политика на программный код

Tags: opensource, privacy

Если программа опен сорс (с открытыми исходниками), то я могу брать, менять код под свои нужды? Могу ли я задействовать программу в своих коммерческих целях? Переименовать?

Особенно интересует gyazo.com, на сайте у них есть прайваси полиси, но там ни слова про изменения исходников, на гитхабе тоже не понятно какая лицензия.

Как быть?!

**UPD:** 
Я пишу файлообменник, много нового придумал ,как его улучшить, вот одной из фишек на нем хочу видеть обмен скриншотами, взяв эту прогу за основу и допилив ее под свои нужды.
Затем хочу, чтобы называлась она также, как и сайт, под который делаю.

Так вот, что можно, что нельзя, относительно этой лицензии?
И вообще, какая там лицензия?! не пойму, не нахожу!

Comment: А причем тут конфиденциальность?

Comment: Много разных лицензий в опенсорсе крутится. Надо конкретную читать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Особенно интересует gyazo.com, [...], на гитхабе тоже не понятно какая лицензия.

[Джва года назад](https://github.com/gyazo/Gyazo/commit/2f472664f4a12b146b1533ce01201419d4da18e5) было обозначено, что под GNU GPL — это видно сразу же в [README](https://github.com/gyazo/Gyazo/blob/master/README) проекта. Не уточнено, правда, какой версии — это проблемно, т.к. вторая и третья версии несовместимы.

Если Вы хотите взять и допилить полностью своим кодом, то если Вы готовы к тому, что Ваш код будет под какой-то версией GNU GPL, то можно вести разработку до уточнения. Главное — публикуйте исходный код и вообще следуйте требованиям, накладываемым обеими версиями лицензии.

Т.е. Вы можете использовать допиленное решение коммерчески, будь то спец. версия, заточенная под платный сервис, или продажа софта. Но Вы обязаны предоставить исходный код любому пользователю, получившему от Вас эту программу. И предоставить ему аналогичные Вашим права дальше.

Переименование — вопрос не авторского права, а товарного знака. Переименуйте, это даже желательно, чтобы не путать с оригиналом. Но Вы должны, при этом упомянуть на видном месте (см. [текст GNU GPL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#.D0.9F.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.8B_.D0.BD.D0.B0_.D1.80.D1.83.D1.81.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9)) что Ваш продукт основан на Gyazo, за авторством Тосиюки Масуи, и распространяется под GNU GPL.

Если хотите дополнить кодом, который Вам не принадлежит — убеждайтесь, что его лицензия совместима с GNU GPL. Пока неизвестно какой конкретно версии — что совместимо с обеими версиями (например, 3-clause BSD совместима и с GPLv2 и GPLv3). Но если вдруг автор скажет что GPL — оно GPLv2 only — то линковаться с кодом, идущим под Apache License нельзя.  А если код под GPLv3 то нельзя будет использовать код, идущий только под GPLv2.

В [**FAQ по лицензиям GNU GPL**](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html) все описано очень подробно и с кучей примеров — и что Вы можете и что Вы должны. Потратьте пол-часа, прочитайте все, и у Вас, скорее всего, не останется вопросов.

И, в любом случае, создайте на GitHub issue с просьбой «Please clarify GNU GPL version (v2/v2+/v3/v3+?)» — авторам дел на пол-минуты и всем будет хорошо и однозначно понятно.

(Privacy policy и terms of use сайта к коду отношения, в подавляющем большинстве случаев, не имеют, если что.)

Comment: Толковое разъяснение.

Answer (score 2):

Опен сорс опен сорсу рознь. Все зависит от лицензии. Если это GPL - то право модификации дается на условиях предоставления доступа к исходникам. Если LGPL - то дается право встраивания/линка бинарника без ссылки на исходники и т.д.

**Update** обзор популярных open source лицензий можно посмотреть [здесь][1]
Касательно лицензии gyazo.com - посмотрите сами исходники - там должна быть ссылка на лицензию или сам текст лицензии.

Comment: Этож не лицензия. Там в репозитарии есть упоминание GPL в одном месте.

Comment: Аааа, ну вы что такое говорите?! Если нет лицензии, то все права защищены. А не наоборот, пользоваться рассеянностью автора и пиратить.

Comment: @karmadro4 в правилах использования сайта написано, что там все public domain если иное не оговорено, отсюда и вывод, что если в исходниках лицензия не прописана, то это паблик домен и не более того.

Comment: Я не хочу пиратить. Я хочу допилить программу под свои нужды, немного изменив ее и дополнив, поменять название. Можно ли это делать с данной программой?!

Comment: > The Service **allows** users to upload, manage and share images** uploaded by the Account Holder or Guests (collectively called “Users”), content available on the World Wide Web **that is under the public domain**, or content that the Users have permission to use **under a Creative Commons License** or by **any other legally valid agreement** or license between the User and owner of such content

Речь о загружаемых изображениях.

Comment: @butteff, я бы связался с авторами и уточнил по всем пунктам, во избежание. И письмо с разрешением надежно сохранил.

Comment: @karmadro4 да был неправ - пробежался по диагонали, правлю ответ

Answer (score -2):

> то я могу брать, менять код под свои
> нужды?

Да

> Могу ли я задействовать программу в
> своих коммерческих целях?

Да но не предствлять программу как собственную

> Переименовать?

Нет, нельзя предствлять программу как собственную

Comment: Дезинформируете, читайте [FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html)

Comment: @Palmervan, вот интересно (отбросим коммерческие цели) я взял код (в общем случае из нескольких программ), местами поменял его и добавил свои функции. 

Что дальше? Как нужно представлять новый код ? Ссылаться на все кусочки ?

Напишите, пожалуйста (раз знаете).

Comment: @avp, ваши патчи остаются вашими, остальное остается собственностью автора и используется как автор вам **разрешил**. Читайте FAQ же. Если никак не разрешил, то и использовать нельзя.

Comment: @karmadro4, зачем советовать **изучать GPL** (Вы даете ссылку не нее), если задан конретный вопрос (про куски кода) ?

Вы (лично Вы) как считаете ? Что надо с ними делать в тексте **уже своего** файла ?

Comment: @avp речь идет о программе не кусках кода!

Comment: @avp а как нужно правильно поступить? (Мне не спора для, а самообразования ради).

Comment: Ну что касается gpl -- тут всё просто. Включили кусок в свой прожект -- прикладывайте gpl ко всему прожекту. Если противоречит условиям, на которых Вы используете другие куски -- облом. (Как вариант -- связываетесь с автором, и если он лицензирует для Вас свой труд на других условиях, то поступаете в соответствии с этими условиями)

Comment: @avp, повнимательнее, пожалуйста, я настоятельно рекомендую изучить **FAQ** по GPL, а не продираться через саму лицензию. Ваш гипотетический файл будет под той же самой лицензией что и первый кусок копипасты, который вы вставили.

Comment: Так и я не для спора, а @Palmervan я задал (в комментарии) конкретный вопрос про куски кода, надеясь что он знает верный ответ.

@Palmervan, так что с чужими кусками делать ? Откомментировать их как-то по особенному (со ссылками) или просто не задумываться о такой ерунде ?

Comment: Я на копипастах и огрызках кода не специализируюсь!

Comment: 1. Если хотя бы одна строка GPL-кода включена в Ваш проект, Вы обязаны распространять свой код под GPL, приложив текст и обеспечив доступ к исходным кодом. Однако, если Вы не распространяете программу, а используете для внутренних нужд, то обеспечивать доступ к исходникам не обязаны. Этим пользуются некоторые компании (например, Google), модифицируя ядро Linux, но не показывая патчи.

Comment: 2. Ссылаться на авторов исходного кода не обязательно, но считается правилом хорошего тона. По традиции ссылку оформляют в заголовочном комментарии, либо так  
    Copyright (C) 2001-2011 Первый автор
    Copyright (C) 2011-2012 Вы  
или используя выражения типа 'partly based', 'derived' и т.п.  
Ссылку на оригинальных авторов можно также поместить в сопроводительные файлы: README, AUTHORS и т.п.

Comment: > модифицируя ядро Linux, но не показывая патчи

в GPLv2 есть исключение на ядро, кстати.

Comment: в GPLv2 есть исключение на ядро, кстати

Оно о другом - [распространяя исходный код приложения, не требуется прикладывать исходный код компилятора и ядра](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.txt):

    However, as a special exception, the source code distributed need not include anything that is normally distributed (in either source or binary form) with the major components (compiler, kernel, and so on) of the operating system on which the executable runs, unless that component itself accompanies the executable.

Comment: Помимо, GPLv2 допускает включать в ядро закрытые модули. Но Google с модифицированным диспетчером потоков и модулями ФС не попадает даже под эту лазейку.

Comment: GPLv2 не допускает закрытых модулей. Проприетарные модули имеют свободную прослойку под какой-нибудь BSD. Т.е. линковка выглядит так Ядро (GPLv2) ↔ прослойка-адаптер (BSD) ↔ блоб драйвера (проприетарная лицензия).